# Stop markup being pasted into WYSIWYG?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Im making a CMS for a client who will be copying and pasting content into the body of nodes. I want to remove certain markup from coming through (eg inline styles) but allow other markup (p and br tags).

With the html filter I can stop certain markup being displayed but its still there in the content when you edit the node. Is there a way of stopping some markup from coming through at all? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Sanitizable](http://drupal.org/project/sanitizable) and [Paste Format (filter, clean-up pasted text)](http://drupal.org/project/pasteformat). The first cleans up on save, the second actually at paste.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the [WYSIWYG Filter](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter) module. It allows to restrict all described things.

[image]

After installation you will be able to configure its settings in the "Input formats" section.

Comment: This looks like the standard html filter in that it filters the output only

Comment: This worked for my use case. Although the undesired markup is still in the DB, it does not get rendered (which in my case, avoided having to cleanup all existing nodes)

Answer (score 0):

[CKeditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) is very complete and you can setup more functions than wysiwyg.

You can even decide with tag you want when you press enter or shift+enter.

It's very complete, have a look at it.

Comment: Im already using this. I can see how to limit the outputed html only.

Comment: It's like you need a Paste as plain text, let me do some research.

Comment: If you go on ckeditor configuration page, and under advanced you find "Force pasting as plain text" . For me this works. Try it.

Comment: I thought this would but its not working

Comment: Hi jdln, I've just tried it and it works. I pasted text from word and from different website. It does what you want. You should check all the filters, the allowed html tag and the other configurations.

Comment: What other settings would I need to change? I want to filter whats pasted into the editor not clean the output up after saving. Wouldnt the filters and allowed html tags only affect after saving?

Comment: Oh, so basically if you copy <div class="asd">blablabla</div> you want to paste just blablabla. Right?

Comment: Yes thats what I want. Or even better would be a transform so <div> could be changed to <p>, <p> would be left in and <span> would be removed and not replaced with anything.

Comment: mmm so it's something you should do with js... there should be a way... what have you found so far? what about this?have you tried it http://drupal.org/project/pasteformat ?

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to look into BU editor. You can set up wyswyg buttons for the type of code to allow.